# Pyquery invalidates html code

Tags: html, building, pyquery

I was using pyquery to construct a webpage:

```
> page = PyQuery('<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="tools.min.js"></script></head><body></body></html>')
> print page
Output: <html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"/><script type="text/javascript" src="tools.min.js"/></head><body/></html>
```

The script (and body) tags aren't supposed end like that though.  Firefox ignores the rest of the header.

I tried breaking the above up into single elements (ie adding one script tag at a time), but to no avail:

```
> page = PyQuery('<html><head></head></html>')
> page.find('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"/></script>')
> page.find('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="tools.min.js"></script>')
Output: <html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"/><script type="text/javascript" src="tools.min.js"/></head><body/></html>
```

The same thing happens with `<iframe/>` tags (forced to use these due to youtube), they don't get closed by firefox and all proceeding code is ignored.

How can I force pyquery to close these using a separate close tag, as I believe, is according to html standards.

Oh and if anyone's wondering, I'm not doing it all in beautifulsoup because (1) I get beautifulsoup errors and (2) it's a deprecated package, the author stopped supporting it about a year or two ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
page = PyQuery('<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js">\n</script><script type="text/javascript" src="tools.min.js">\n</script></head><body></body></html>')
```

It also works with iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `print page.__html__()` to dump a html or, better, `print page.html(method='html')`